# How to index a list of tensor in Keras model definition

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Suppose we have the following definition of keras model

```
def build_model(ls):
    x = Input(shape=(1,), name='input_index')
    gs = [K.constant(x) for x in ls]

    idx = Lambda(lambda x: K.cast(x, 'int32'))(x)
    y = Lambda(lambda x: gs[x[0, 0]])(idx)

    model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
    return model
```

Here, we pass a list of `ndarray:ls` to initialize the model. Inside the model definition, `gs` converts `ls` into a list of constant tensor. Input `x` gives the index `i` and the model should have returned the corresponding tensor `gs[i]`. However, the model given above is correct.

Is there any way I can do such thing in keras ?